# PyObjC and custom blocks

Tags: cocoa, macos, pyobjc

The official documentation says that it is possible to use custom blocks in python code but you need to create metadata. I haven't found an example of it.

My question is how to create, use and distribute metadata for custom blocks.

**Example**

```
@interface SomeClass

- (void)doSomethingWithCompletion: (void (^)(SomeObject *obj, NSError *error))myBlock;

@end


def pythonMethod():
    def completion(obj, error):
        # staff
    foo = SomeClass.new()
    foo.doSomethingWithCompletion_(somehow_pass_completion)
```

The question is how `somehow_pass_completion` should look like and how to provide metadata for `myBlock`.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let my know, if my example doesn't specify the question.

Comment: No, that's perfect. I may not get to the answer till later today, but I know what you need to do.

Comment: Okay, answer posted! Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metadata that is mentioned is information, stored in XML format, about the return and argument types of Objective-C methods. It is needed so that the PyObjC bridge knows what type to turn a Python object into when passing it back across to Objective-C code. You can check out the metadata if you like; it's in .bridgesupport files inside of the PyObjC framework. The AppKit metadata, for example, is at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/AppKit/PyObjC.bridgesupport It can be generated for any Objective-C code you have using Apple's `gen_bridge_metadata` command-line tool. Theres a [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gen_bridge_metadata.1.html) for that utility, and [`man 5 BridgeSupport`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/BridgeSupport.5.html) is also informative.<sup>1</sup>

PyObjC provides the functions `objc.registerMetaDataForSelector` and `objc.parseBridgeSupport`, both of which allow you to add metadata for your methods, using either Python dicts (the former function) or the XML format described in the BridgeSupport man page (the latter). Examples of using `registerMetaData...` are available in the pyobjc source at: [pyobjc/pyobjc-core/PyObjCTest/test_metadata*](http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-core/PyObjCTest/test_metadata_py.py)  (and nearby `test_metadata*.py` files)<sup>2</sup>.

Just as an example, this is the metadata for [`-[NSSavePanel beginWithCompletionHandler:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000309-SW24), which takes a block as an argument:

```
<method selector='beginWithCompletionHandler:'>
    <arg index='0' block='true' >
        <retval type='v' />
        <arg type='i' type64='q' />
    </arg>
</method>
```

The arg type specifiers are the same [Type Encodings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) that you get back from using `@encode` in Obj-C. The metadata for your method should be quite similar.

So, since you have your methods prototyped in Objective-C, you should be able to run them through `gen_bridge_metadata` to create a .bridgesupport file that you can include in your project, then use `objc.parseBridgeSupport` to read that file in. Using `objc.registerMetaDataForSelector` has also worked for me in the past; check out the linked examples above.

Once you have the metadata in the PyObjC "system", you can use any old callable object as an argument for the method that takes a block:

```
def pythonMethod():
    def myCompletionHandler(obj, error):
        pass
foo = SomeClass.new()
foo.doSomethingWithCompletion_(myCompletionHandler)
```

This is all kind of an amalgam of a few other posts I've made here about PyObjC: [PyObjC and Returning Out Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353403/pyobjc-and-returning-out-parameters-i-e-nserror/5271245#5271245) | [Indexed Accessor Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376463/pyobjc-indexed-accessor-method-with-range/5336824#5336824) | [Problem with openPanelDidEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809340/problem-with-openpaneldidend-in-pyobjc-in-10-6/5272077#5272077). You might want to take a look at those too.

It's been a while since I've futzed with this, so I may have left something out. Don't hesitate to ask for more info if you still can't get this to work. Don't give up too easily, though -- the bridge is a funny beast and sometimes you just have to show it who's boss!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Another Apple doc you should read is: [Generating Framework Metadata](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/GenerateFrameworkMetadata.html).</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>I discovered these via a pyobjc-dev [mailing list thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pyobjc.devel/5373)</sub>